# Shifted laplace transform derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have a linear ODE that has terms that are shifted, for example

$$\frac{d^k f(x-n)}{dx^k}$$

from a general equation

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \frac{d^k f(x-n)}{dx^k}$$

where $a_k$ are constants. Since the ODE was linear i assumed a Laplace transform would be easy to apply to this, but a laplace transform for something like $\frac{df(t-n)}{dt}$ gives

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{df(t-n)}{dt} e^{-st}dt=\int_{n}^{\infty} \frac{df(t)}{dt} e^{-s(t+n)}dt$$

$$=e^{-ns}[\int_{n}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt}(f(t) e^{-st})dt - s\int_{n}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}]$$

$$=e^{-ns}[-f(n^{-})e^{-ns}-s(F(s)-\int_{0}^{n} f(t)e^{-st}dt)]$$

Is this correct? What about the last term, is there an evaluation for it or is it computer only? Is there an easier way to solve the above ODE?

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transforms applies to functions that are assumed to be zero on $t < 0$. The shifted function $f(t-t_0)$ would be zero on $t < t_0$. The time-shifting property says

$$ \int_0^\infty f^{(n)}(t-t_0)e^{-st}dt = \int_{t_0}^\infty f^{(n)}(t)e^{-s(t+t_0)}dt = e^{-t_0s} \int_0^\infty f^{(n)}(t)e^{-st}dt $$

where the last integral is just the Laplace transform of $f^{(n)}(t)$

Comment: Is there a way to solve the above ODE using another method, like Fourier transforms then or some other method and does it still give a partial integral? Technically, the solution of my problem is not defined for $x \leq 0$, though values could be obtained through interpolation.

Comment: What is the ODE? I think you should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Ok i've edited the question to include the full equation

Comment: This is called a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). It's better to write it as $$ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k f^{(k)}(x) = f(x+x_0) $$ You're free to look up different methods of solving it, or ask another question about it. I'm not going to answer it here, as it's now a completely different problem.